# Are there any alternative methods for reverse connections that bypass firewalls?

Tags: firewalls

I'm doing a PenTest on a server. I have an RCE vulnerability on it, but when I try to do a reverse connection via `netcat`, the firewall blocks it. Is there any other methods used for reverse connections, like DNS or something?

Comment: How do you know the firewall blocked you and something else is not to blame?

Comment: Sure you can use DNS, or even ICMP. Does the firewall restrict those?

Comment: I recently answered a very similar question, have a look here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/214282/how-to-exploit-rce-vulnerability-for-machine-on-local-network/214290#214290

Answer (score 1):

There are lots and lots of methods to connect one machine to another (that's what you are trying to do). What you need to know is what the firewall will allow. Map out the firewall and then you will know what to do. The technique is called "firewalking".